# jquery document on click with ":not" not working

Tags: jquery

I am sorry if the title is terrible, I was really trying to figure out how to word this lol

What I am trying to do is I have links that a user will click on, within the `<a>` I have a class called `not_me` when the user clicks on that I don't want to fire the event. I tried to use `:not(.not_me)` but the click event is still firing. What am I missing?

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).on("click",".co_link:not(.not_me)", function() {

})
```

**HTML**

```
<a class="co_link"><span>Here is some other stuff </span><span class="not_me">Click Me</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event target of the `.not_me` element does not match the `.co_link` selector. You're actually targeting an element like: `<a class="co_link not_me">`.

You will need to stop propagation on the `.not_me` element first:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.not_me', (e) => { e.stopImmediatePropagation(); });
$(document).on('click', '.co_link', (e) => { alert('clicked'); });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="co_link"><span>Here is some other stuff </span><span class="not_me">Click Me</span></a>
```

Comment: That was perfect! Thanks Ben